# How to disable auto-generated accessors/mutators in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

**Problem**

Its seems regardless of whether you define a field as public or private Groovy will make it publicly accessible via an auto-created accessor. There are a few posts here that suggests this only happens if your field is not declared private. I can speak for every version but for Groovy 2.5, and I suspect higher, thats definitely not the case.

Example

```
private Collection<BeanDefinition> unknownLocalBeans = new HashSet()
```

The variable unkwownLocalBeans is accessible to everyone despite the fact that I don't want anyone to have access to it, including through a getter method.

**Question**

Is there a way to get actual private access in Groovy or to disable the auto-generation feature? I have classes that should NOT have accessors and having them available is inviting developers to do things they shouldn't.

Comment: problem not in auto-generated accessors. problem that groovy performs dynamic access to methods, and properties through java reflection. and java allows to access private methods and members through reflection. If caller class or method will be annotated with `@CompileStatic` then private will be restricted even during compilation.

Comment: @daggett Thats an interesting point. Looking into it now and will follow up. Thank you for your post.

Comment: As workaround create method getUnknownLocalBeans   that throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can access private members in Groovy has nothing to do with auto-generated accessors. Officially, the ability to access private members is a bug in the implementation of Groovy i.e. there's nothing in the Groovy language spec. that says you *should* be able access private members.

However, this bug has existed for so long, that it's almost accepted as a de facto feature. The likelihood of this bug ever being fixed is very low, because there are a lot of programs that rely on the ability to access private members, which would break if it were fixed.

Personally, I think it's a shame that there's no way to encapsulate data within a class, but others disagree and find the ability to access private members useful, e.g. when writing tests.

It may be the case that you cannot access private members of a class annotated with `@CompileStatic`, but this annotation introduces some restrictions which you may not like.

Comment: I see. Whats the point of auto-generated accessors if all fields are public?

Comment: I guess I could post that as a separate question.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil yes, please post a separate question, because the answer will need more than a short comment.